# enforce a function to wait till mouse clicked

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, mouseevent, wait

I have been stuck for the past month and I did not find any solution.
my problem is I am writing a game of four players. three are computers and one human.

so there are a play() function for computers and one Overridden play() function for human. 
 here is the function which human player will use

```
 @Override
 public void play(){
    for(int i=0 ; i <13;i++){
    getJLabels()[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt)
        {
            int Index = getIndex(getJLabels(), (JLabel)evt.getSource());
            getJLabels()[Index].setIcon(getHand()[Index].getBackSide());
            getPlayerJLabel().setIcon(getHand()[Index].getCardImage());
            setObjectForPlay(getHand()[Index]);
        }
    });
}
    temp = getObjectForPlay();
    return temp;
}
```

Other three players use play() and return an object automatically. i mean the mouselistener is only for this human.play() function

i am running these functions from  nested loop. when a round of loop complete every player complete his play() turn and then next loop start. and so on.

Problem is computers play() functions are not waiting for human to click.
I want that when loop play the human Play() then wait for human to click and return object. when human play() end with click then next computer play() call

My english is poor thanks for understanding
waiting for nice solution

Comment: Please help me i am tired and stuck

Comment: recommend you put a Java tag on this for better support.